# How to convert values stored/returned as timestamps in sql query to dd-mm-yyy

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have a query where columns  `sb.start_time AS shift_date` and `MIN(cs.start_time) AS first_completed_shift` return values stored as timestamps, but I want the format to be only dd-mm-yyyy

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 sb.start_time AS shift_date,  --I want this as dd-mm-yyyy format
 i.title AS industry,
 wl.name AS venue_name,
 w.first_name,
 w.last_name,
 MIN(cs.start_time) AS first_completed_shift, --I want this as dd-mm-yyyy format
 i.title AS industry,
 w.interviewed_on AS induction_date,
 d.issue_date AS edbs_issue_date,
 d.created_at AS date_dbs_added,
 a.user_id  
FROM shift_bookings sb
JOIN jobs j ON sb.job_id = j.id
JOIN listings l ON j.listing_id = l.id
JOIN work_locations wl ON l.venue_id = wl.id
JOIN workers w ON sb.worker_id = w.id
JOIN completed_shifts cs ON w.id = cs.worker_id
JOIN documents d ON w.id = d.documentable_id
JOIN audits a ON d.id = a.auditable_id
JOIN industries i ON j.industry_id = i.id
WHERE sb.shift_id IN (253106)
AND d.document_type_id = 33
AND a.auditable_type = 'Document'
GROUP BY
 sb.start_time,
 wl.name,
 w.first_name,
 w.last_name,
 i.title,
 w.interviewed_on,
 d.issue_date,
 d.created_at,
 a.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a proper `date` value, then cast the timestamp to a date:

```
sb.start_time::date AS shift_date
```

you will need to adjust the `group by` then.

and

```
 MIN(cs.start_time::date) AS first_completed_shift
```

You can also use [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) to format the timestamp to any format you want as you want it.

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, you consider accepting it (click the check mark on the left).